# Translation of "to the best of the author's knowledge"

Tags: traduction, anglais, académique

As far as I know

> to the best of my knowledge

is rendered by

> pour autant que je sache

For

> to the best of the author's knowledge

should I use

> pour autant que l'auteur sache

or is it better to use

> au meilleur de la connaissance de l'auteur

or another structure?

**Context**

To the best of the author's knowledge is a more formal way to say as far as he or she (the author) knows. Say that one has written down something in a scientific publication. He or she has thoroughly searched the relevant literature but he or she could not find a single reference of the result in question.

The author has searched carefully but he or she cannot searched the WHOLE literature of an enormous field like, e.g. elasticity. So one uses this expression. I am not a French native speaker but I thought it should not sound so awkward in French.

As a real example (taken from Freed's book: Soft Solids):

> *"The Eulerian velocity gradient l is typically denoted as L in the literature. That notation is reserved here for the Lagrangian velocity
>   gradient defined in Eq. (2.24), which is a field not found in the
>   literature **to the best of the author’s knowledge**."*

Comment: "à ma/notre connaissance..." is fairly used too, but "au meilleur de la connaissance..." is not.

Comment: @SteffX Thus, if I understood correctly, there is not a direct French interpretation of "to the best of the author's knowledge" ? One should use the personal structure "à ma connaissance" ?

Comment: — That's right! The "best of ... knowledge" had an equivalent in French (which I can't remember now) but is no longer used. Maybe we considered that "to the best of author's knowledge" is a bit weird. What was the author doing before? Not using his "best knowledge"?

Comment: @SteffX  To the best of the author's knowledge is a more formal way to say as far as he (the author) knows. Say that you write down something in a publication. You have searched in the literature but you could no find a single reference of your result. You have searched carefully but you cannot searched the WHOLE literature of an enormous field like, e.g. continuum mechanics. So one uses this expression. I am not a French native speaker but I think it should not sound weird.

Comment: @SteffX  See a real example: (taken from Freed: Soft Solids) "The Eulerian velocity gradient l is typically denoted as L in the literature.
That notation is reserved here for the Lagrangian velocity gradient defined
in Eq. (2.24), which is a **field not found in the literature to the best of the author’s
knowledge**.

Comment: Is the person referring to "the author" found in the phrase at issue the author him/herself (as The Maestro in Seinfeld always calls himself "The Maestro" & similarly, as "The Jimmy" in another episode always refers to himself in the third person)?

Comment: @PapaPoule The author of the book is referred to himself as you said. But this is a common practice in scientific literature. Even French authors use this structure in scientific publications (in English language scientific books/articles and the like). I thought it is used in French as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Une combinaison des solutions trouvées semble convenir parfaitement ; on se passe tout simplement de « meilleur » : [à la connaissance de l'auteur](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/%C3%A0+la+connaissance+de+l%27auteur.html).

Cette forme correspond à l'anglais « as far as the author knows », synonyme de « to the best of the author's knowledge ».

ADDITION

Une objection par jlliagre (voir commentaires), laquelle je ne trouve pas entièrement convaincante, mais qui se comprend au vu de l'usage restreint de la traduction utilisée ci-dessus a suscité une nouvelle possibilité;

> pour autant que l'auteur puisse le certifier 
>   (*parution importantes, rapports, livres, et lorsque l'auteur est celui qui parle, pas dans les lettres et pas dans la langue parlée*)

Comment: Les expressions *à ma/ta/sa/notre/votre connaissance* sont courantes mais *à la connaissance de l'auteur* me semble rare, voire quasiment inusité (en dehors de *porter à la connaissance de* mais qui n'est plus une proposition indépendante). Je suggérerai simplement *selon l'auteur*, même si cette expression exprime plus de doute que *à sa connaissance*.

Comment: On trouve trois exemples dans le Linguee qui concernent exactement ce contexte (à la référence fournie dans ma réponse) ; de plus on trouve le syntagme « à la connaissance de tout le monde » ; pourquoi faire de cette construction une construction figée, qui n'aurait la signification voulue que lorsque le possesseur est représenté par un adjectif ? N'est-il pas plus naturel de concevoir la chose ainsi ? Il me semble que l'on puisse dire, par exemple,  « Il n'existe pas, à la connaissance de quiconque, de reptiles volants. ». Qu'est-ce qui préviendrait cette extension qui semble si légitime ?

Comment: « Selon l'auteur » a un inconvénient majeur : c'est un terme qui sous-entend tout autant des opinions de l'auteur que des connaissances ; il est donc assez vague à cet égard ; de plus, il semble y avoir une question quant à la personne dont il est question, cela étant assez subjectif : on ne déduit pas automatiquement que la personne qui écrit soit celle désignée comme étant l'auteur dont il est question.

Comment: une raison supplémentaire d'éviter « meilleur » dans « au meilleur de la connaissance de l'auteur », outre le calque anglais qui n'est pas vraiment français, est que le neutre s'imposerait grammaticalement : au mieux et non au meilleur, comme au pis et non au pire … Eh oui, il reste du neutre en français ! « À la connaissance de l'auteur » ne me choque pas du tout, « Selon l'auteur » est effectivement ambigu, « Pour autant que l'auteur sache » est totalement inusité et lourd (calque de « pour autant que je sache » qui lui est courant).

Comment: @5915961T «Au mieux de » serait une expression figée selon le TLFi (Au mieux de. **De la façon la plus appropriée à**. Vacance à l'artiste d'user, au mieux de ses désirs, des moyens techniques ainsi rendus disponibles) ; il s'ensuit que cette possibilité n'est pas envisageable, d'emblée. De plus on passe de « bon » (best) à « bien »  et le critère qui importe est la validité de la connaissance plutôt que son degré d'intérêt ; cependant, cette question de nécessité du neutre me laisse perplexe.

Comment: "À la connaissance de l'auteur" ou "selon l'auteur" sont les seuls options pour moi. Le reste est trop lourd. "Pour autant que l'auteur puisse le certifier" est bien trop lourd et pompeux. Je ne l'utiliserai pas et l'ai jamais entendu.

Comment: @Mat Non, je ne crois pas du tout que « Pour autant que l'auteur puisse le certifier » (**(1**) soit ou lourd ou pompeux ; on dit très naturellement dans une certaine variété de tons, sinon moi personnellement, « Pour autant que je sache », « Pour autant que l'on sache », et ces expressions sont très similaires ; dans le cas de « **(1)** » on émet un degré de doute prudent. Évidemment il est entendu qu'il ne s'agit plus de la langue parlée **et** de la langue écrite comme dans le cas des autres possibilités mais seulement de la langue écrite. Je vais d'ailleurs ajouter ce détail (Merci).

Comment: @LPH "Pour autant que je(il, elle...etc) sache" est une expression idiomatique pour moi. Ça se dit et s'écrit couramment et ne peut être comparé à un autre emploi similaire. Concernant « Pour autant que l'auteur puisse le certifier », à l'écrit, ça peut encore passer (je trouve ça pompeux néanmoins), mais surtout pas à l'oral. De plus, il n'y a absolument rien à certifier ici. Nul besoin de rajouter un sens à cette traduction. La traduction doit impliquer la limite de la "connaissance de l'auteur", "à la connaissance de l'auteur" est donc parfait car cela s'inscrit dans ce schéma.

Comment: @Mat Oui, cela est juste, la connaissance est du type certifié, ce qui n'est pas exactement celle de tout le monde, mais dans le cas présent nous parlons d'auteurs et du produit de leur travail  de spécialiste et de leur expérience lesquels reposent sur un édifice de certification ; il me semble que nous ne sommes pas bien loin du compte pour ainsi dire. « Pour autant que[…] sache…» pourrait être l'archétype de toute un usage libre que vous comprendrez en faisant la petite recherche suivante, mais « pour autant que » n'est pas lié uniquement à ce verbe. (champ 1)

Comment: @Mat  Tapez « Pour autant que » dans l'interface du TLFi (http://atilf.atilf.fr/), comme si c'était un mot ; cliquez « 20 » ; cliquez « paragraphe » puis cliquez « valider » ; vous pouvez maintenant considérer des exemples variés d'usage libre.

Comment: @LPH 1-"« pour autant que » n'est pas lié uniquement à ce verbe". Je n’ai jamais dit ça. J’ai dit que l’expression « pour autant…sache. »est idiomatique. Je n’ai pas parlé de « pour autant que », nuance !
2- atilf.atilf.fr… soyons sérieux. Le site précise qu’il n’est plus mis à jour depuis 1994. Il ne suit plus l’évolution de la langue française. Selon la même recherche (qui n’avait rien à voir avec la discussion, voir point 1), au moins la moitié de ces expressions sont liées à ladite expression donc je ne vois pas l’intérêt de votre argument.

Comment: @LPH 3- « leur expérience lesquels reposent sur un édifice de certification». Non, pas forcément. Un auteur n’est pas et n’a pas forcément à certifier ou être certifié. Ce n’est que votre point de vue et je trouve que ça détourne la traduction. 
4- Je cloture ma contribution à cette question ici car il ne sert à rien de trop en rajouter. Malgré une divergence de point de vue, merci de votre participation.

Answer (score 1):

Complément à la réponse.

Il y a une question homologue dans English SE :

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65723/analogue-of-to-the-best-of-our-knowledge

On lit :

> When you say "to the best of my/our knowledge," you're saying that
> "you think your statement is true, because it is based on what you
> know/believe, but you are not completely sure" [Macmillan].
>
> So any phrase that expresses that lack of complete certainty that fits
> the context will do. In the context of an academic paper, you might
> say:
>
> We believe that this is the first work that shows how...

Je crois que cette idée se trouve dans le commentaire de @jlliagre :

"(...) Je suggérerai simplement **selon l'auteur**, même si cette expression exprime plus de doute que à sa connaissance."

> Nous croyons que cela est le premier travail qui illustre/montre/... que...